# I try array OBJECT3D

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js

I'm just a beginner with Three.js. I would like to push my 'model' object to an array. My code should be fine, I think. 
I have my var nextobj = [ ];.

```
function Loadobj() {
    var mx = [-1500,1500] , my = [350,350] , mz = [-1000,-1000];
    var nextobj = []; //Keep Array Model

    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
        var mtloader = new THREE.MTLLoader(); 
        mtloader.load('obj1/az-mp0076.mtl', function (materials) {
        materials.preload(); 
        var objloader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objloader.setMaterials( materials );
        objloader.load('obj1/az-mp0076.obj', function (object){ 
            model = object;
            model.position.set(mx[i],my[i],mz[i]);
            scen.add(model); 
            nextobj.push(model); 
            console.log(nextobj.length);  //This here my check data Object
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Step 1:
     I loop < 1 Object it's show

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ktGD.jpg
Step 2
I loop > 1 object not show but my data show  Complete

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIZVv.png
How can I push my  objects array? Many thanks.
I'm not sure what's wrong in my code.

Comment: `I loop > 1 object not show but my data show ` - according to loop `for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)` it ends up when i > 1.

Comment: I am not sure I got your question. But objloader.load() is asynchronous. maybe you try to draw your models after the loop before all  models are actually loaded asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run `Loadobj` recursively or make it a promise. Inside of for loop you have two callbacks (for loading materials and objects). The problem is that looping executes without waiting for each item (of callback) to be loaded, it runs synchronously. But all methods related materials/objects loading are asynchronous (they have callbacks and have results of loading only inside callback functions). To have fully loaded objects you need to make sure you manipulate the results of loads methods only after items (of callbacks) have been loaded and and call `Loadobj` again only after previous execution of `Loadobj` has been finished.
Using recursive function:

```
var mx = [-1500,1500] , my = [350,350] , mz = [-1000,-1000];
var nextobj = []; //Keep Array Model
var numOfObjs = 1;
var start = 0;
function Loadobj() {
  if (Loadobj == numOfObjs) return;
  start++;
  var mtloader = new THREE.MTLLoader(); 
  mtloader.load('obj1/az-mp0076.mtl', function (materials) {
    materials.preload(); 
    var objloader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objloader.setMaterials( materials );
    objloader.load('obj1/az-mp0076.obj', function (object) { 
      model = object;
      model.position.set(mx[start],my[start],mz[start]);
      scen.add(model); 
      nextobj.push(model);
      console.log(nextobj.length);
      Loadobj();
    });
  });
}
```

Another way is using Promise:

```
function Loadobj(obj) {
  return loadMaterials()
    .then(function(materials) {
      return loadObjs(materials, obj);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
   });
}

function loadMaterials() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var mtloader = new THREE.MTLLoader(); 
    mtloader.load('obj1/az-mp0076.mtl', function (materials) {
      materials.preload(); 
      resolve(materials);
    });
  });  
}

function loadObjs(materials, obj) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var objloader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objloader.setMaterials( materials );
    objloader.load('obj1/az-mp0076.obj', function (object){ 
      var model = object;
      model.position.set(obj.mx, obj.my,obj.mz);
      // scene is available globally
      scene.add(model); 
      nextobj.push(model);
      resolve(model);
    });
  });
}

var objs = [
  {
    mx : -1500, 
    my: 350, 
    mz: -1000
  },
  {
    mx: 1500, 
    my: 350, 
    mz: -1000
  }
];

var nextobj = []; 

// use reduce to iterate over objs
objs.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  return Loadobj(obj);
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: Excuse me Sir. i need to know  how to break example First

Example 2 so good for  thank you so much.

Comment: @ThachthaphongNengJumNong you mean how to implement it or some part of it is'not clear for you?

Comment: yes it's load more but i don't know how to break; for example first sir.

Comment: @ThachthaphongNengJumNong I've updated answer with more explanations

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you again. Hahaha. I spent 3 days editing my Code .
you are teacher for me  many thank sir.  (learn more for me)